# Blender Point Cloud access

Tags: point-clouds

Is there possibility how to **access** to the points in **Point Cloud** object in Python API Bleder > 2.92?

I want to change position of each point, set color and set scale.

I tried the code below. This change the position of point in Point Cloud.
But how can I set color or size?

```
for point in obj.data.points:
    point.co = Vector((1,1,1))
```

PS: I need to work with individual points. Is there a way?
Ex: Geometry Nodes? 
Thanks for your advices

Comment: FYI: I'm on Blender 2.92 and there is no point cloud object. Any custom build? Appears on the todo list: https://developer.blender.org/T75717 though.

Comment: You have to allow it in Edit -> Preferences -> Developer Extras -> Experimental tab ->  New Point Cloud Type

Comment: Nothing in there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSkmc.png - *Developer Extras* is enabled anyway.